# Add Google API to meteor project

Tags: google-api, meteor

i'm trying to link Google API to my meteor project but cant seem to make it load.
Docs say to add

```
script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

to the header, which we cant do straight in meteor.

I tried getting a local copy of the script and adding it to client folder but still get 'gapi is not defined' when loading. This approach worked with filepicker.io but not on this one.

Any idea where or how to load the library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unauthorized access to Google Calendar API post request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227222/unauthorized-access-to-google-calendar-api-post-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out: The best way was to use Google RESTful api. You can see a working example at [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227222/unauthorized-access-to-google-calendar-api-post-request)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Meteor's built in external services for auth, they have a specific one for google: 
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice

To load the client API just include this in the `<head>` section of your application's main html file.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

You can confirm it has loaded correctly by running `gapi` in the console

Comment: Not really. That's a great option for login service, but google exposes a full API to manipulate Calendar, tasks, maps and most other services programatically from different platforms like ruby, python, js and such.. I'm trying to import that library in my project so I can add Events and tasks to gCalendar and gtasks

Comment: what happens when you try to load it in the mainapplicationfile.html file?

Comment: well, when using "gapi.client.load("calendar","v3") on meteor.startup console returns a 'Cannot load method 'load' of Undefined. After page is loaded I can call 'gapi' from console and issue the same command correctly from console. Looks like the object is not available from meteor.startup or something.  Tried calling the function from template.rendered but didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the script tag, set the appropriate attributes
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap';
script.async = true;

// Attach your callback function to the `window` object
window.initMap = function() {
  // JS API is loaded and available
};

// Append the 'script' element to 'head'
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

See [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Dynamic).