# Unauthorized access to Google Calendar API post request

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use Google calendar REST API within Meteor I can use any GET method without any problem, but when I try to create an event in a calendar I get an Unauthorized access error.

I got my code on the following gist [code](https://gist.github.com/4489908)

Basicaly I use Meteor.loginWithGoogle and get an AccessToken, with it I can get any calendar or userInfo from google, but when I try to insert an event I get the following message:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events 401 (Unauthorized)

any ideas?

Comment: Hey Persech, please accept some more answers to your questions. It's considered polite here to accept answers and it helps increase the chance that you'll get good answers in the future.

Comment: I'd be more than glad to accept answers to the questions, not only it's polite but also it's what I think the site is for, but I feel like marking as good an answer which dont fully solves the problem is no good to anyone who would look for a similar question. I reviewed all my questions (which are not many) and checked a good answer. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After quite a good while of trying got it right..

Added the following file to my client folder

```
 Accounts.ui.config({requestPermissions: {google: 
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks']}}, requestOfflineToken: {google: true})

gCal = 
  insertEvent: (cliente, poblacion, texto, fecha)->
  #to-do calendar devuelve un Event Object que incluye un ID
  # si incluimos este id como campo en la alerta podremos despues
  # eliminar el evento en el calendario directamente desde la app
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events"
    event=  {
      summary: cliente
      location: poblacion
      description: texto
      start:
        "date": fecha
      end:
        "date": fecha
      }
    evento = JSON.stringify event
    console.log evento
    Auth = 'Bearer ' + Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken
    Meteor.http.post url, {
      params: {key: 'INSERT-YOUR-API-KEY-HERE'},
      data: event,
      headers: {'Authorization': Auth }
      }, 
      (err, result)->
        console.log result
        return result.id
```

if you logged in thru {{loginButtons}} and then call insertEvent it works like a charm.