# In my meteor app, how do I make authenticated google API calls on behalf of my user?

Tags: meteor, google-api, google-calendar-api

**Background**: This is my first standalone web development project, and my only experience in Meteor is building the Discover Meteor app over the last summer. I come from about a year of CS experience as a side interest in school, and I am most comfortable with C and C++. I have experience in python and java.

**Project so far**: I'm creating a calendar management system (for fun). Using accounts-google, I have created user accounts that are authenticated through google. I have requested the necessary permissions that I need for my app, including 'identity' and 'calendar read/write access'. I've spent the last week or so trying to get over this next hurdle, which is actually getting data from google.

**Goal**: I'd like to be able to make an API call to [Calendar.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) using a GET request. I've already called `meteor add http` to add the GET request functionality, my issue comes with the actual implementation.

**Problem**: I have registered my app on the developer console and set up Accounts using the client ID and secret, but I have not been able to find/generate my 'API key' for use in the request. [Here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) is the google guide for creating the access token by using my (already) downloaded private key. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around an implementation on the server side using JS because I don't have a lot of experience with what is mentioned in the HTTP/REST portion of the implementation examples. I would appreciate some help on how to implement a handshake and receive an access token for use in my app. If there is a call I can make or some package that will handle the token generation for me, that would be even better than implementation help. I believe an answer to this would also benefit [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982118/how-to-use-google-contacts-api-in-meteor)

The SO answer that I've been referring to so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543159/4259653 Some of it is in spanish but it's pretty understandable code. He has an API key for his request, which I asked this question to help me with. The `accounts-google` documentation isn't really enough to explain this all to me.

Also an unrelated small question: What is the easiest way to deal with 'time' parameters in requests. I'm assuming JS has some sort of built-in functionality that I'm just not aware of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started trying to implement all of this myself on the server side, but was wary of a lot of the hard-coding I was doing and assumptions I was making to fill gaps. My security prof. used to say "never implement encryption yourself", so I decided to take another gander for a helpful package. Revising search criteria to "JWT", I found jagi's `meteor-google-oauth-jwt` on Atmosphere. The readme is comprehensive and provides everything I need. Following the process used in [The Google OAuth Guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount), an authorization request can be made and a key generated for making an API call.

Link to Atmosphere: https://atmospherejs.com/jagi/google-oauth-jwt

Link to Repo: https://github.com/jagi/meteor-google-oauth-jwt/

I will update this answer with any additional roadblocks I hit in the Google API process and how I solved them:

Recently, I've been running into problems with the API request result. I get an empty calendarlist back from the API call. I suspect this is becuase I make an API call to my developer account rather than to the subject user. I will investigate the problem and either create a new question or update this solution with the fix I find.

Fix: Wasn't including the 'sub' qualifier to the JWT token. Fixed by modifying JWT package token generation code to include `delegationEmail: user.services.google.email` after `scope`. I don't know why he used such a long designation for the option instead of `sub:` as it is in the google API, but I appreciate his package nontheless.

I'm quickly becoming proficient in this, so if people have meteor-related google auth questions, let me know.

Comment: The package referenced in this answer was made for Google Service Accounts, so it will *not* work for authenticating on behalf of your user. For a discussion of the details, see https://github.com/jagi/meteor-google-oauth-jwt/issues/2

Comment: I actually am using a service acct to do this. I ended having to do it to store people's accounts connected to google, and it's pretty critical for making calendar requests on behalf of them, which is what my app does.

Comment: I am on the same 'page' as fullstack. Google services accounts should not access data on behalf of users. The correct way to do what you are doing is Web access + offline_token + refresh_token as the user for those permissions upfront. I would be very interested to know how you are getting access from users to "allow" the permissions using a service account, unless as per the docs this is domain wide.

Comment: Sorry, I abandoned this project for a while and couldn't figure out which e-mail I used for stackexchange. I used a service account to set up permissions, and then allowed users to authenticate and give me permission to mess with their stuff (through the google accounts package).

In my case, my app needs a service account because it will be optimizing group calendars behind the scenes. (ie. scheduling meetings efficiently for a small workgroup). This requires making some shared calendars that are owned by the service account, not the users.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your research. I have also asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341573/manipulate-google-calendar-data-for-users-registered-on-meteor-app-with-a-google), and right now I am looking into the package you recommend. I have considered this [meteor-google-api](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api) package, but it looks abandoned.

Regarding your question about time manipulation, I recommend MomentJS. There are many packages out there; I am using `meteor add mrt:moment`

**EDIT:** MomentJS now has an official package for Meteor, so use `meteor add momentjs:moment` instead of the `mrt` command above

Below is a snippet of what moment can do. More documentation [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

```
var startTimeUTC = moment.utc(event.startTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format();
//Changes above formatting to "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" (ISO 8601)
//which is acceptable time format for Google API
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I just got back to development on my project and saw this. I'll be using it instead of some of the hacky stuff i did before.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT USE SERVICE ACCOUNTS AS POSTED ABOVE!**

The correct approach is to use standard web access + requesting offline access. The documentation on the api page specifically states this:

> Typically, an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.

The only exception to this is when you are using google apps domain accounts and want to delegate access to your service account for the entire domain:

> Authorizing a service account to access data on behalf of users in a domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating domain-wide authority"

This makes logical sense as a user must be allowed to "authorise" your application.

**Back to the posters original question the flow is simple:**

1) Meteor accounts google package already does most of the work for you to get tokens. You can include the scope for offline access required.

2) if you are building your own flow, you will go through the stock standard process and calls as explained on [auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

**This will require you to:**

1) HTTP call to make the original request or you can piggyback off some of the internal meteor calls : Package.oauth.OAuth.showPopup() -- go look at the source there are more nifty functions around there.

2) Then you need to create an Iron router server side route to accept the oauth response which will contain a code parameter that you will use to exchange for tokens.

3) Next use this code to make a final call to exchange the "code" for the token + refresh_token

4) Store these where ever you want - my requirement was to store them not at the user level but multiple per user

5) **Use a package like** [GoogleAPI](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api) this wraps up Google API calls and refreshes when required - it only works when tokens are stored in user accounts so you will need to rip it apart a bit if your tokens are stored somewhere else (like in my case)